# Как на Яндекс Картах JavaScript API V3 реализовать по кнопке полноэкранный режим

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Не смог найти как в новой версии Яндекс Карт (V3) реализовать полноэкранный режим по кнопке. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Такой кнопки в новом API больше нет. Растягивание блока с картой на всё окно вам следует реализовать самостоятельно.

Comment: А готовых решений никаких нет общедоступных?

Comment: Готовые решения появляются для популярных запросов. Полноэкранный режим вообще сам по себе мало кому нужен. Может вам нужно в модальном окне разворачивать или только на всё окно, а не реальный фуллскрин. Изменение размера карты есть в примерах Яндекса. Переключение браузера в фуллскрин тоже достаточно документировано в сети. Просто объедините эти два метода так, как вам удобней. Не получится — приносите получившийся пример. Посмотрим, что могло пойти не так.